# Populating value of an array

Tags: php

I have a function

```
public function get_detail($subscriberid)
    {
    $bigArray = array();

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *  from prospect_requests WHERE subscriber_id = '$subscriberid'");
    //$user_data = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $no_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result))
    {

$bigArray[] = $row;
    }
     return json_encode($bigArray);

    }
```

i am calling this function by using the user class object from my html and it is returning the data in form array

I am tring to populate those value in my html table do i am using the following method

```
<table>
 <?php
 $ary = json_decode($user->get_detail($uid));
         echo "<tr>"         
         foreach($ary as $key=>$value) {
              echo "<td>";
              print  $key['$value'];
              echo "</td>";
           }
   echo "</tr>";

  ?>
```

the above foreach is not printing for me

But when i am printing the `print_r($ary);`
I am getting the desire array of arrays .

Please tell me why  values are not populating in table.

**Update output of print_r($ary)**

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 133 [customer_id] => caason [subscriber_id] => ELECTRO_SUBS_12800 [extension_id] => [vendor_number] => [product_code] => [prospect_email1] => naveen.ggg@bhng.com [prospect_phone1] => +575445 [prospect_email2] => [prospect_phone2] => [prospect_title] => IT Engineer [prospect_company] => gggg [prospect_name] => ggdf [prospect_message] => MESSAGE [create_timestamp] => 2012-12-20 16:28:46 [update_timestamp] => 2012-12-20 16:33:15 [status] => 0 [track_id] => 201660a2-4a66-11e2-abeb-00151771ff65 [initiated_by] => SMS [subscriber_email] => g.dgdg@gfg.com [vendor_email] => ananda.rao@talismanuc.com ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 134 [customer_id] => caason [subscriber_id] => ELECTRO_SUBS_12800 [extension_id] => [vendor_number] => [product_code] => 12800 [prospect_email1] => gpadaki@sadhanasystems.com [prospect_phone1] => +756767863 [prospect_email2] => [prospect_phone2] => [prospect_title] => TESTING232 [prospect_company] => Sadhana Systems [prospect_name] => 7dfgfg [prospect_message] => MESSAGE [create_timestamp] => 2012-12-22 02:43:51 [update_timestamp] => 2012-12-22 22:42:36 [status] => 0 [track_id] => 380024bc-4b85-11e2-abeb-00151771ff65 [initiated_by] => SMS [subscriber_email] => naveen.fgf@ggf.com [vendor_email] => g.f@talismanuc.com ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 135 [customer_id] => caason [subscriber_id] => ELECTRO_SUBS_12800 [extension_id] => [vendor_number] => [product_code] => 12800 [prospect_email1] => naveen.vghg@hgh.com [prospect_phone1] => +25454 [prospect_email2] => [prospect_phone2] => [prospect_title] => Sw Engineer [prospect_company] => Talisman [prospect_name] => Naveen [prospect_message] => MESSAGE [create_timestamp] => 2013-01-02 16:32:38 [update_timestamp] => 2013-01-02 16:35:48 [status] => 0 [track_id] => d1da0adc-549d-11e2-abeb-00151771ff65 [initiated_by] => SMS [subscriber_email] => naveen.ggjg@hgjh.com [vendor_email] => gf.fhg@hgh.com ).......))
```

Comment: This is not normal array, its array object. Check php manual to see how to handle array objects

Comment: ohhh could you please give me some hints

Comment: Use json_decode($user->get_detail($uid), true); to convert to associative array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
json_decode($user->get_detail($uid), true);
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

**When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.**

Answer (score 0):

[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) - Takes a JSON encoded string and converts it into a PHP variable.

```
mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] )
```

assoc - When `TRUE`, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

`json_decode($user->get_detail($uid), TRUE);`

if you are to access the values as an array.